# What is the best way to determine what's locking up SQL Server using a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

Recently our SQL Server is getting bogged down by something. I was wondering what is the best way to check what could be causing the problem by querying the database. This is the best I've found so far:

```
SELECT
    SPID            = s.spid
,   BlockingSPID    = s.blocked
,   DatabaseName    = DB_NAME(s.dbid)
,   ProgramName     = s.program_name
,   [Status]        = s.[status]
,   LoginName       = s.loginame
,   ObjectName      = OBJECT_NAME(objectid, s.dbid)
,   [Definition]    = CAST([text] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM      sys.sysprocesses s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle)
WHERE 
 s.spid > 50
ORDER BY
    DatabaseName
,   loginName
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your favorite SQL Administrative or META Queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095123/what-is-your-favorite-sql-administrative-or-meta-queries)

Comment: If you *use* the `database-administration` tag, you should realize you're in the wrong place. This site is about **programming** - you need to go to [Serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) for admin stuff - that's where the sysadmins and DBA's hang out...

Comment: not duplicate, prior question was in wrong format. Last time i logged in i don't think server fault existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good place to start.  You should also be looking at the waits by using the sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks DMV which will tell you which resource is causing each process to wait.

```
select wait_type, sum(wait_duration_ms) sum_wait_duration_ms, avg(wait_duration_ms) avg_wait_duration_ms, count(*) waits
from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
group by wait_type
```

Comment: Could you please include (in your answer) a select statement that does this?  If not, then how would you do this?

Comment: I've added some code which you can use to find the wait types which are causing problems.